# Issues with Ruby's Logger when it is packaged?

Tags: ruby, packaging

Has anyone had any problems with Ruby's [Logger](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) class when it it packaged up into a gem or otherwise? In my project, Logger stops logging to files once packaged.

Comment: What do you mean by “packaged”? It's part of the standard library; I hope you haven't copied it into your project…

Comment: when you initialize logger do you use a filepath to log to ? is that path still there when your app is packaged ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking the question elsewhere and getting an answer, but I am posting my solution here for thoroughness. Once I packaged my application, the relative file paths I had for logging were no longer working. Once I changed those paths to absolute paths (C:/ ....) my application began logging again.

```
require("logger")

Shoes.app { 
    logger = Logger.new("C:/Users/Max/Desktop/loggertest/logfile.log")
    logger.level = Logger::WARN

    logger.info "#1 this is an info"
    logger.warn "#2 this is a warn"
    logger.debug "#3 this is a debug"
    logger.error "#4 this is an error"
}
```

Comment: try using `File.expand_path('../logfile.log', __FILE__)` for proper file-system traversal.